# Select fields and then join OR join and then select fields?

Tags: performance, oracle, select, join

lets say I need to join 3 tables (`T1`, `T2`, `T3`) and lets say the each one of those tables has 30 columns and millions of records. Would it be faster to get the relevant fields and then join the results or join the 3 tables and then get the relevant fields?

I will simplify (assume the values in a,b,c are unique):

(please, the code will probably won't look like I meant it to look, I will appreciate if somebody could fix it)

option 1:

```
SELECT
  T1.a,
  T2.c
FROM
  T1,T2,T3
WHERE
  T1.a = T2.b
  AND T2.b = T3.c
```

Or, option 2:

```
SELECT 
  t_T1.a,
  t_T2.c
FROM
  (SELECT a FROM T1) t_T1,
  (SELECT b FROM T2) t_T2,
  (SELECT c FROM T3) t_T3
WHERE
  t_T1.a = t_T2.b
  AND t_T2.b = t_T3.c
```

Please assume that on the tables I'm working on, every second counts and matters so this may look like a stupid example but I really need to know which one will be faster.

BTW, using ORACLE with PLSQL developer 10.0.2.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Mahmoud, thank you for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for option 1.

In general, in SQL, you want to use the most compact representation for your query. This gives the optimizer the most "freedom" to restructure your query.
While your option 2 might not be much trouble for most optimizers, there are cases when if you take this to the extreme the optimizer isn't going to be able to chose another execution path than what you've actually spelled out.

As David has mentioned, you don't have to specify the execution order; another reason to go for option 1.

Finally, humans have to be able to maintain the SQL, so go for the simplest representation, which in this case is also option 1.

Answer (score 1):

They probably resolve to the same optimised query, so there would be no difference.

SQL is a [fourth generation language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) so you should assume that forcing evaluation order is generally not going to work.

Comment: I wanted to vote up but apparently I need 15 reputation in order to do that.